# How to use angular material drop down to to see on each select an the "the company name" from the sql server

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, typescript, string-interpolation

How to fix it so it will work, want to use angular angular material drop down to to see on each select an the "the company name" from the sql server
I would like to bind the dropdown select and it will let me choose company name that i already imported

> TS-https://prnt.sc/p2eg21
>
> HTML-https://prnt.sc/p2eguq

**Component:**

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource,MatSort} from '@angular/material';
    import { User } from 'src/app/services/user.model';
    import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';



    @Component({
      selector: 'app-companyinteraction',
      templateUrl: './companyinteraction.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./companyinteraction.component.css']
    })
    export class CompanyinteractionComponent implements OnInit {
      // displayedColumns: string[] = ['CompanyName'];
      // dataSource:MatTableDataSource<User>;

      public companiesNames:User[];
      constructor(private prodService:UserService) { }


      ngOnInit() {
        const ob = this.prodService.getUsers();
        ob.subscribe(users => {
          this.companiesNames = users;
          console.log(this.companiesNames);
          console.log('Test from CompanyInteraction'); 
        });
    //...
}
```

**Template:**

```html
    <h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let User of companiesNames" [value]="companyName">
            {{companyName}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the "User" interface?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/p2f8jj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h4 class="valuePicker">Select Company</h4>
<mat-form-field class="valuePicker">
  <mat-label>Select Company</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let p of companies" [value]="p.CompanyName">
        {{p.CompanyName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Thanks.... figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```html
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let user of companiesNames" [value]="user.id">
        {{user.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Then the mat-select will give you the id of the selected one. Read the documentation to get the selected value here: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

Comment: Offcourse that would not work as is, because when i posted the answer there was no information about your User object. You obviously have to adabt it to your logic.